# Reading data from CSV file and insert to SQL using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, csv

Hi i have test folder in that daily we copy one csv file we dont use any code to copy file we just drag and drop from local. CSV file have 11 columns but i want only 3 columns data in sql. so i created 3 columns in sql. My aim is to read file from folder and insert those 3 columns data to sql. I will run the task daily using task scheduler if file found in folder it need to import data to sql

Comment: why not `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong LOAD DATA INFILE is just command i guess i need to run the task daily using task scehduler

Comment: MySQL is an Oracle product, and SQL Server is Microsoft. It's highly unlikely you're using both of them simultaneously, and they're vastly different in features and syntax. You need to [edit] your post to remove the tag that does not fit your question. Tags have meaning here. Please use only those that are actually applicable to your question instead of just adding those that sound familiar. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get the column names the same in the source and destination?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer yes i have same column names in csv and sql. But i csv i have 11 columns i want only 3 so i create only 3 columns

Comment: Ok, so 'recs' DataTable has 11 columns in it?

Comment: ON what line is the error? You may wish to consider using SQL Agent and / or SSIS to do this instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.  Simply choose the fields (columns) you want to load.

```
Protected Sub uploadButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles uploadButton.Click

    ' declare CsvDataReader object which will act as a source for data for SqlBulkCopy
    Using csvData = New CsvDataReader(new StreamReader(fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream, True))
        ' will read in first record as a header row and
        ' name columns based on the values in the header row
        csvData.Settings.HasHeaders = True

        ' must define data types to use while parsing data
        csvData.Columns.Add("varchar") ' First
        csvData.Columns.Add("varchar") ' Last
        csvData.Columns.Add("datetime") ' Date
        csvData.Columns.Add("money") ' Amount

        ' declare SqlBulkCopy object which will do the work of bringing in data from
        ' CsvDataReader object, connecting to SQL Server, and handling all mapping
        ' of source data to destination table.
        Using bulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=sa;Password=")
            ' set the name of the destination table that data will be inserted into.
            ' table must already exist.
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Customer"

            ' mappings required because we're skipping the customer_id column
            ' and letting SQL Server handle auto incrementing of primary key.
            ' mappings not required if order of columns is exactly the same
            ' as destination table definition. here we use source column names that
            ' are defined in header row in file.
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("First", "first_name") ' map First to first_name
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Last", "last_name") ' map Last to last_name
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Date", "first_sale") ' map Date to first_sale
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Amount", "sale_amount") ' map Amount to sale_amount

            ' call WriteToServer which starts import
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(csvData)

        End Using ' dispose of SqlBulkCopy object

    End Using ' dispose of CsvDataReader object

End Sub ' end uploadButton_Click
```